# XSD select type from attribute name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML-snippet.

```
<grade term="One" type="simple">4.7</grade>
<grade term="Two" type="complex">2.1</grade>
```

The attribute type can either be "`simple`" or "`complex`". The `simple` type can contain all decimals from 1.0 to 5.0 and the `complex` type can only contain the values match the pattern `[123]\.[037]|5\.0|4\.[07]`.

How can I build an XSD to validate the content of the grade depending on the selected type (either `simple` or `complex`) ?

I've come up with:

```
<xs:simpleType name="complex">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1.0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="simple">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:pattern value="[123]\.[037]|5\.0|4\.[07]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="gradeType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="complex">
      <xs:attribute name="term" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="type" use="required" type="complex"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

but this generates a lot of errors:

> Cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'simple' Is Not A Valid Value For
>   'decimal'., Line '8', Column '66'. Cvc-attribute.3: The Value 'simple'
>   Of Attribute 'type' On Element 'grade' Is Not Valid With Respect To
>   Its Type, 'complex'., Line '8', Column '66'. Cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1:
>   'simple' Is Not A Valid Value For 'decimal'., Line '9', Column '66'.
>   Cvc-attribute.3: The Value 'simple' Of Attribute 'type' On Element
>   'grade' Is Not Valid With Respect To Its Type, 'complex'., Line '9',
>   Column '66'. Cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'simple' Is Not A Valid Value
>   For 'decimal'., Line '10', Column '66'. Cvc-attribute.3: The Value
>   'simple' Of Attribute 'type' On Element 'grade' Is Not Valid With
>   Respect To Its Type, 'complex'., Line '10', Column '66'.

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: What you want to do requires XSD 1.1.  See duplicate link for an example.

Comment: Not even with type inheritance ? I'm only allowed to use 1.0 so if there is no other solution this is unsolvable. Thanks.

Comment: Conditional Type Assignment requires XSD 1.1.  In XSD 1.0, you differentiate type by element name: `simpleGrade` and `complexGrade`.